# Explanation of proof of logarithm power rule

Tags: algebra-precalculus, logarithms, proof-explanation

Can someone explain how to get from steps $(1)$ to $(2)$ in this proof of the logarithm power rule? How is the "equivalent exponential expression found? The power rule:

> For any positive $x$, any number $p$, and $a>0,a\ne1$, $$\log_ax^p=p\cdot\log_ax$$

---

The proof:

> $(1)$ Let $b=\log_ax$.
>
> $(2)$ Then, writing an equivalent exponential equation, we have $x=a^b$.
>
> $(3)$ We raise both sides of the latter equation to the $p$th power, getting $x^p=a^{bp}$
>
> $(4)$ Now we can write an equivalent logarithmic equation: $\log_ax^p=\log_aa^{pb}$, which simplifies to $\log_ax^p=pb$.
>
> $(5)$ But $b=\log_ax$, so we have $\log_ax^p=p\cdot\log x$

Comment: Use definition of $\log_a(x)$ as that number to which $a$ must be raised to get $x.$

Comment: See whether this helps you: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_logarithmic_identities#Cancelling_exponentials

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's basically just using the definition of a logarithm.

The statement $x = a^b$ is equivalent to $a^{log_ax} = a^b$. We're raising $a$ to the power of both sides.

Just like $e$ and the natural log $\ln$ or $\log_e$, $a$ and $\log_a$ cancel out